# Excel 2013 Pivot Table refusing to summarise identical values - returns duplicate results. Why?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table

I've encountered a bizarre issue whilst building a simple pivot table in Excel. Here are my data: I've created a simple table with col C containing values in A divided by those in B. I have included the formula in col D just to be crystal clear.

[image]

Now here's the weird thing - when I build a pivot table from Col C, I get two versions of the number 6:

[image]

This is crazy! Why has Excel not aggregated both 'versions' of the number 6 into one line? I did some further tests: isnumber() returns true for both 6s, and even the test for equivalence (='*1st 6*'='*2nd 6*') returns true also! Why is Excel failing to summarise these identical values in the pivot table?

I'm guessing it's something to do with 1.2 / 0.2 returning a float, and 12 / 2 returning an integer (as might happen in python), but there's nothing in Excel to tell me what data types I'm dealing with. A rounding error perhaps? And if the two 6s are not the same, why does my equivalence test return true?

If I convert the two 6s to integers then the pivot table returns the expected results. However, I don't believe I should have to do this, and most users wouldn't expect to either. What's going on here? Expected behaviour, or bug?

Comment: so you already have the answer, it's related to rounding (maybe 1.2/0.2 is `6.0..01`, but just displayed as `6` and also rounded when you perform any calculations with it. It's borderline to be a bug, but anyway I don't think  we can provide any more information here as your question could be truly answered by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

If you convert Column C to an integer using `INT` function, then the PivotTable generates as you expect. It is a floating point issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What's confusing is that Excel 'covers up' some rounding issues (which is why it returns TRUE when asked if one 6 = the other). If you evaluate =INT(1.2/0.2) in the spreadsheet, you'll get "6". Try that in the Immediate Window however ( ?INT(1.2/0.2) ) and it returns 5. In short, Excel doesn't handle this quirk particularly gracefully, and it doesn't give any clues to the user as to what's going on.